# iOS Integrating highcharts

Tags: ios, uiwebview, highcharts

I am using highcharts in my app. The files are structured as shown in this

[image]

Below shown is the code i am using to load the html.

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"pieChart" ofType:@"htm"];
NSString *html=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];   
[_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

But nothing loads in my webview. The piechart.htm file has reference to highcharts.js file. I doubt highcharts.js file is not being loaded. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What are the contents of `*html` and `*path` when you call `loadHTMLString`?

Comment: Also, is it `piechart.htm` or `piechart.html` ... your question has one and your code another.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the below for your path:

`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];`